# Area and perimeter of detected objects

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

How can I find the area and perimeter of objects detected using sobel edge detection algorithm?

Did not find any soution

Comment: Update your question with the code

Answer (score 1):

Sobel operator is a filter kernel. After convolution of an image with that kernel you get an approximation of the image's first derivative. It can be used to get gradient information. Its most common application is edge detection.

Sobel is no object detection algorithm. Hence it cannot give you perimeter or area of any object. You need further intermediate steps.

To choose an algorithm that suits your needs one would have to know your image. Otherwise no useful answer can be provided.

If you have a simple binary image google for blob detection or labeling.
To get objects in the first place google for image segmentation.